# How can I use DocumentRoot and server-status within an Apache virtual host?

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.2

I have this virtual host setup as the first in a list of virtual hosts. It is

```
<VirtualHost localhost:80>
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot "/www/drupal5"

<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from localhost
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

The rest of the virtual hosts are below and expressed as *:80.

When I include the DocumentRoot in this virtual host, requests on the server to `http://localhost/server-status` always hit /index.php through rewrite rules in /www/drupal5/.htaccess. If I remove the DocumentRoot declaration, /server-status requests work fine, but then the site isn't available at all at `http://localhost/`.

How can I get `http://localhost/server-status` to work as well as the site to load at `http://localhost/` ?

Comment: Can you post the contents of `/www/drupal5/.htaccess`? Hopefully, it is possible to modify the rewrite rules so that requests for /server-status are not rewritten.

Comment: The clarification I think I need is: is it possible for mod_rewrite to overwrite what happens to a /server-status path even though it's been handled in the <Location>

Answer (score 15):

Found the solution when I googled 'server-status mod_rewrite'. Coincidentally it was answered in a drupal forum: http://drupal.org/node/52511

Adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/server-status` to the rewrite rule for redirecting all traffic to /index.php fixed it.

Very confusing that mod_rewrite can rewrite a uri that's already set a handler.

Answer (score 5):

Just add a blank vhost entry to the top of the vhost configuration file e.g.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: How would it solve the original question?

Comment: Apache is defaulting to the OPs first named vhost, their Drupal install, instead of going to the server-status page. An empty vhost will stop the processing for /server-status from being sent to Drupal and allow the status page to load

Comment: But won't this new "first" VirtualHost catch *all* traffic and thus prevent all normal (non-server-status) traffic from flowing through to the Drupal application VirtualHost?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Apache 2.3 or higher, you should also be able to use the `END` flag in your VirtualHost entry, to save having to modify the .htaccess files.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /server-status
RewriteRule ^ - [END]
```

Should prevent the subsequent rules from rewriting things.